# http post is not working using cUrl (libcurl)

Tags: curl, c++builder, libcurl, c++builder-2010

I'm making simple http post request using libcurl to index.php file on my web server
that has the following simple code writing post data to a file

```php
if (isset($_POST['abc'])){
    $log="abc.log";
    $h=fopen($log,"w");
    fwrite($h,$_POST['abc']);
    fclose($h);
}
```

while my written c++ code implementing http post request is the following

```c
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    curl=curl_easy_init();
    string url=AnsiString("http://127.0.0.1/curl/index.php?abc=123").c_str();
    string data="abc=3434";
    if (curl) {

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,AnsiString("abc=3434").c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,AnsiString("http://127.0.0.1/curl/index.php").c_str());
        res=curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
```

First, posting is enabled `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`

Second, if I debug this code i get `CURL_OK` status in `res` (return value)
and also TCP 127.0.1:80 will be established everytime i run the code monitoring via `netstat -ano 15` but the file `abc.log` is empty

What's wrong with this??
Haven't you any idea pointing me to the right way?

Thank you
in advance!

Comment: What _is_ wrong? What's not happening? What about your webserver log files? Do they show anything?

Comment: the file `abc.log` is empty :(

Comment: Well, you're not setting any post data (that part is commented out). So that's expected.

Comment: when I change `$_POST['abc']` to $_GET['abc'] in my php file and run `index.php?abc=qwerty` via browser it writes to a file!

Comment: That's not the request you're sending via C++. Please use your webserver logs to see exactly what you're sending from the C++ side.

Comment: `127.0.0.1 - - [03/Mar/2012:16:09:18 +0500] "GET /curl/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 -` what minus stands for in the end ?? Actually, it's sending GET method!

Comment: changed `$_POST['abc']` to `$_GET['abc']` and also `  curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_HTTPGET,1);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,AnsiString("http://127.0.0.1/curl/index.php?abc=23234").c_str());
` is not working, if, say, it sends GET request!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE` helped!
`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE,data.Length());`

Apache log says it's ok you've sent POST

`127.0.0.1 - - [03/Mar/2012:17:39:06 +0500] "POST /curl/post.php HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

Comment: I came to an idea that it's possible to send POST  req at all using c++ using the above code! Great !